# Pass data from a Material Dialog to parent component

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-services, angular-components

I have component with a button (TeacherComponent) that opens a Material Dialog. In that dialog, is a text area and rating stars from where the user can send a feedback. After the Submit button is clicked I need to get all that data (PopUpFeedbackModel) and send them to the parent component.
I create a service for this, but it's not working, if I get the data in ngOnInit() method, if I create a button and after the feedback window is closed, that button is pressed I got the data.

PopUpFeedbackService:

```
export class PopUpFeedbackService {
    private _feedbackSource = new Subject<IPopUpFeedback>();

    constructor() {
    }

    sendFeedback(popUpFeedback: IPopUpFeedback) {
        this._feedbackSource.next(popUpFeedback);
        console.log(popUpFeedback);
    }

    getFeedback() {
        return this._feedbackSource.asObservable();
    }
}
```

PopUpFeedbackContent (the content of Dialog):

```
export class PopUpFeedbackContentComponent implements OnInit {
    private _feedbackForm: FormGroup;
    private _starRating: number;
    private _feedback: PopUpFeedback;

    constructor(
        private _formBuilder: FormBuilder,
        @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) private _name: any,
        private _popUpFeedbackService: PopUpFeedbackService) {
    }

    onSubmitFeedback() {
        this._popUpFeedbackService.sendFeedback(new PopUpFeedback(this._name.name, this.getFeedbackMessage(), this._starRating));
    }
}
```

The `onSubmitFeedback()` method send the feedback to TeacherComponent.

TeacherComponent:

```
export class TeacherComponent implements OnInit {
  private _feedback: IPopUpFeedback = null;
  @Input() private _teacher: ITeacher;

  get teacher(): ITeacher {
    return this._teacher;
  }

  constructor(
    private _feedbackService: PopUpFeedbackService,
    private _teacherService: TeacherService) {
    this._feedbackService.getFeedback().subscribe(feedback => this._feedback = feedback);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._teacherService.sendTeacherFeedback(this._feedback).subscribe();
  }

}
```

So how can I get the value from Dialog with that PopUpFeedbackService, after the Dialog is closed. The Submit button contains `mat-dialog-close`.

Comment: I'm going to edit your question because you're using a **material** dialog, not an *angular* one, and for the answer, I'm going to refer you to [the documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview#sharing-data-with-the-dialog-component-) which explains it thoroughly.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I read the documentation. But I have multiple components in where I need to send the data from Dialog, not just in one component.

Comment: Then do it in your service and use rxjs to share an event.

Comment: I solved the problem with two separate components for teachers and courses feedbacks, but with the same content for Dialog. Thank you!